# Server Request Type Unknown or Not Defined in Security.xml (qualtrics)

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

Any idea why I get this error message when I try to save my survey on Qualtrics? I already a discussion going on their question platform: https://www.qualtrics.com/community/discussion/comment/24029#Comment_24029  (left without reply)

Comment: I answered on the Qualtrics Community...contact Qualtrics Support. This really isn't an appropriate Stackoverflow question, so it will probably be downvoted/flagged/closed.

Comment: yes, I contacted them and put their answer on the Qualtrics Community! ok sure